# Simple clock that counts down from 30 seconds and executes a function afterward

Tags: javascript

I have a game that gives a time limit and I need to display a countdown clock for the users and stop the game once the time is up such as 30 seconds. How can I do this in javascript?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) to set up a timer. Within this timer, you can update some text in your page and when the time is up, you can call whatever function you want:

```js
var timeLeft = 30;
    var elem = document.getElementById('some_div');
    
    var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
    
    function countdown() {
      if (timeLeft == -1) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        doSomething();
      } else {
        elem.innerHTML = timeLeft + ' seconds remaining';
        timeLeft--;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="some_div">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to actually post code.

Comment: another good tutorial https://www.growthsnippets.com/30-second-countdown-timer-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

Check out `setTimeout` and `setInterval`:

http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Comment: Thanks, that is a really good link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout()` function for this like :-

```
let timeElm = document.getElementById('timeElm');
let timer = function(x) {
 if(x === 0) {
    return;
 }

 timeElm.innerHTML = x;

 return setTimeout(() => {timer(--x)}, 1000)
}

timer(30);
```

In this, we use recursion and gave it a `setTimeout()` of `1000ms` for reducing the time.