# Set a 30 minute timer that starts with a button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a timer that times out after 30 minutes. I want to start with a button. This is what I have so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>30 minute count down.</p>

    <button onclick="countDown()">Start</button>
    <div id="status"></div>

    <script>
    function countDown() {
     var secs = 1800;
       var mins = secs / 60;
     var element = document.getElementById(status);
     element.innerHTML = "You have "+mins.toFixed(2)+" minutes";
     if(secs < 1) {
      element.innerHTML = '<h2>You have no time left!</h2>';
     }
     secs--;
     setTimeout('countDown()',1000);
    }
    </body>
    </html>
```

It isn't working. 
Please help a newbie! 
Thanks

Comment: getElementyID is passing a variable..... needs to be in quotes  'status'

Comment: `It isn't working` what does it mean?

Comment: there's quite a few problems really

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple clock that counts down from 30 seconds and executes a function afterward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435776/simple-clock-that-counts-down-from-30-seconds-and-executes-a-function-afterward)

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435776/simple-clock-that-counts-down-from-30-seconds-and-executes-a-function-afterward

Comment: I'm so new to this. I apologize for not asking my question correctly. I will try to be more specific in the future and not just say "it isn't working".  Thanks for the links and the information! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use quotes for `getElementById` - like `"status"`. Also change how your function works:

```js
var secs = 1800;

function countDown() {
  var mins = secs / 60;
  var element = document.getElementById("status");
  element.innerHTML = "You have " + mins.toFixed(2) + " minutes";
  secs--;
  setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
  if (secs < 1) {
    element.innerHTML = '<h2>You have no time left!</h2>';
    secs = 1800;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>30 minute count down.</p>

<button onclick="countDown()">Start</button>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
function countDown() {
    var secs = 1800;
    var mins;
    var element = document.getElementById('status');
    
    setInterval(function(){
      mins = secs / 60;
      element.innerHTML = "You have "+mins.toFixed(2)+" minutes";
      if(secs < 1) {
          element.innerHTML = '<h2>You have no time left!</h2>';
      }  
      secs--;
    }, 1000)  

}
```

```html
<p>30 minute count down.</p>

<button onclick="countDown()">Start</button>
<div id="status"></div>
```